# OnConfiguring event of the Identity Context class does not fire when writing a record to the AspNetUsers table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using Identity in Asp.net core and my context inherits from a NetDevPackAppDbContext class which is a very cool assembly created by Eduardo Pires. I'm overriding the "OnConfiguring" event but it never fires. The moment I record a new "User" I need this event to be triggered so that I can obtain the connection string so that I can record it in the correct database, as I am working with multiple "tenants". Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks!

[NetDevPack repository](https://github.com/NetDevPack/NetDevPack)

My Context:

```cs
public  class UsersDbContext : NetDevPackAppDbContext 
{
    
    public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<NetDevPackAppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        if (_currentTenantRepository is not null)
        {
            
        }           
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //Não dispara :(

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    }
}
```

My Factory class:

```cs
public class UsersDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<UsersDbContext>
{               
    public UsersDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);        
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NetDevPackAppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        return new UsersDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `OnConfiguring` is not an event it is a method.

Comment: It executed once per class type and only after executing first query.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy